# Rails creating a new object instead of updating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with editing an object from the admin panel on my app. (It's a political related app, hence the references to Liberal and Conservative, etc).
When I edit a category it creates a new category (with the same name) instead of updating it. I can't figure out why.
I can see from the log that when I edit the category Rails appears to go to the POST route `(POST   /admin/categories(.:format)          admin/categories#create)` instead of the PUT or PATCH route `(PATCH  /admin/categories/:id(.:format)      admin/categories#update)`

Apologies if I am using incorrect terminology, I'm not well versed in Rails.

categories_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < Admin::DashboardController

  before_action :find_category, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy ]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Category created'
      redirect_to admin_categories_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Something was wrong'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    @category.update(category_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Category saved'
      redirect_to admin_categories_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Something was wrong'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy

    redirect_to admin_categories_path
  end

  private
  def find_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :liberal_image, :conservative_image)
  end
end
```

edit.html.slim inside the admin view (using slim):

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
.container
  = link_to 'Manage Categories', admin_categories_path
  h1 = "Edit Category - #{@category.name}"
  = render partial: 'form', locals: { category: @category }

  = simple_form_for @category, url: admin_category_path, method: 'delete' do |f|
    = f.submit 'Delete category', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg'
```

I'm presuming it's something wrong in one of these files but let me know if there's something else I need to copy up there. Thanks !

_form.html.slim

```
 = simple_form_for @category, url: admin_categories_path, method: 'post' do |f|
  div.form-group.required
    = f.input :name, label: 'Category Name'
  div.form-group.required
    = f.input :liberal_image, as: :file, label: 'Liberal Image'
    div.target
  div.form-group.required
    = f.input :conservative_image, as: :file, label: 'Conservative Image'
    div.target
  div.form-actions
    = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn'

javascript:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files;
      var image = files[0]
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(file) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = file.target.result;
        $(event.target).parent().parent().find('.target').html(img);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
      console.log(files);
    });
  });
```

Comment: in update action you have `@article.save`, whereas what you might really want, is `@category.save`

Comment: Can you show the form partial in your question?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I tried that but it's still creating a new category.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Added in form partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd need to see your `form` partial to be clear, but from first glance, you have an issue with your `update` action:

```
def update
   if @category.update(category_params)
     redirect_to admin_categories_path, notice: "Category saved"
   else
     render :edit, error: "Something was wrong"
   end
end
```

You had `@article.update` - I don't know why, because you haven't even set `@article` at all.

--

**Update**

It seems that your form is the cause of the issue:

```
= simple_form_for @category, url: admin_categories_path, method: 'post' do |f|
```

Here, you're sending each request to the `create` action.

You need to use the following:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @category] do |f|
```

Comment: I tried this but still the same problem. When I save it a new category with the same name is created

Comment: Thanks buddy, let's check this out

Comment: That's it Rich ! Well done. Thanks for that. Apologies to everyone else for not putting up the form partial earlier. I didn't think it was part of the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As someone noticed, you are using @article variable that seems to be undeclared. This should cause an ApplicionError, so I think this maybe a simple bug, that your "edit" link actually leads to the "new" action. Does the name field actually contains a category name, or is it empty?

UPDATE: Actually, using @article will not cause an error. But check your links to be sure anyway.

Comment: @article is declared in the articles_controller. I'm not sure actually if that is a good or a bad thing in this particular problem

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with that, but it will create another problem. You can't declare it in the another controller. If you want access to the articles from the category edit view, you need to declare it in the categories controller.

Comment: thanks. I actually don't need to access the articles from the category edit view.